# Infinite convex combinations in a Banach space

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convexity

Let's say that a subset $C$ of a Banach space $X$ is *$\sigma$-convex* if the following property holds:

> For any sequence $(x_k)_{k\ge0}$ in $C$, and for
> any sequence of non-negative real numbers $(\lambda_k)_ {k\ge0}$ with
> $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda_k=1$ the
> series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda_k x_k$ converges to an element of $C$.

(the term $\sigma$-convex seems quite natural for this property, and indeed it is used e.g. in this 1976 [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-66/issue-1/Choquet-simplexes-and-sigma--convex-faces/pjm/1102818223.full); though I'm not certain that this is the standard current terminology).

Clearly, any $\sigma$-convex set is convex and bounded; a bounded convex set need not be $\sigma$-convex (e.g. the convex hull $\Delta$ of the orthonormal basis of $\ell^2$). A *closed* bounded convex set is $\sigma$-convex; and an *open* bounded convex set is $\sigma$-convex, too. Also, the intersection of $\sigma$-convex sets is $\sigma$-convex, and the image of a $\sigma$-convex set via a bounded linear operator is $\sigma$-convex.

> **Question:** is there a topological
> characterization of those bounded
> convex subsets of a Banach space which
> are $\sigma$-convex?

Given the above mentioned facts, a reasonable conjecture could be, that a bounded convex set is $\sigma$-convex if and only in it is a Baire space.
[**edit**] a simple counterexample in $X:=\mathbb{R}\times \ell^2  $ is  $C:=(0,1]\times B\, \cup\,  \{0\}\times\Delta$ where $B$ is the open unit ball of $\ell^2$, and $\Delta$ is the non-$\sigma$-convex set described above. This set is bounded, convex, and Baire, though it's not $\sigma$-convex.

$$*$$

[**edit**] As far as I see, the interesting feature of $\sigma$-convex sets is the following "iteration lemma" (it's a piece of the Open Mapping Theorem, that in my opinion is worth to be a lemma in itself, also because its proof is repeated in several theorems).

> **Lemma.** Let $X$ be a Banach space; $C\subset X$ $\sigma$-convex; $B\subset X$ a
> bounded subset, $0 < t < 1$ be such
> that $$B\subset C + tB \, . $$ Then
> $$(1-t)B\subset C \, .$$

(*proof*: as in the OMT: start from $b_0\in B$, represent it as $b_0=c_0+tb_1$, and iterate; one gets $(1-t)b_0$ as sum  of an infinite convex combination in $C$).  Curiously, this is also a characterization, in that any bounded set $C$ for which the above property holds for any bounded set $B$ (and even for just a fixed $0 < t < 1$) is indeed $\sigma$-convex.

Comment: I'm leaving this as a comment as you ask for a **topological** characterisation.  I don't know one, but I do know an **algebraic** characterisation.  What you describe are **totally convex spaces** as described at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/totally+convex+space in particular, any such set is the image of a unit ball under a continuous map from a Banach space (indeed, an $\ell^1$-space).

Comment: @Andrew:  You are describing the $\sigma$-absolutely convex sets.  

@Pietro Majer: Continuing what Andrew started, IMO the $\sigma$-convex sets are best described as the image of the positive part of the unit ball of an $\ell_1$ space.

Comment: Notice that any subset of the closed unit ball of a Hilbert space (or any strictly convex Banach space) that contains the open unit ball is $\sigma$-absolutely convex, so $\sigma$-absolutely convex sets can be complicated topologically.


Comment: Good point. I've added a remark, just to explain why I become interested in the subject. 

Comment: @Bill: actually your example suggests a simple counterexample to my naive conjecture (bounded, convex, and Baire => $\sigma$-convex), in form of a convex subset $C$,  $B\subset C\subset \bar B$ between an open, non-strictly convex ball, and its closure. Such a set $C$ is certainly Baire, but it may fail to be $\sigma$-convex, if one face of its is not.    

Comment: I should mention that the $\sigma$-convex hull of a set came up naturally in the classification of Banach spaces that have the Radon-Nikodym property through Maynard's concept of $s$-dentability.  Later Davis and Phelps showed that you could use just dentability, so these days no one talks about $s$-dentability. Their paper

http://www.jstor.org/pss/2040618

gives the history, including the work of Rieffel that started this line of investigation.  Or see the book Vector Measures by Diestel and Uhl.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly I misunderstood your question, but I do not see a hope for a suitable characterization because of the following example (inspired by the comment of Bill Johnson): Consider a set $A$ in $\ell_2^2$ ($2$-dimensional Euclidean space) consisting of the union of the open unit ball and some subset of the unit sphere. The set $A$ is always $\sigma$-convex. On the other hand $A$ is (this can be shown directly) homeomorphic to a subset $O$ consisting of the union of the open unit ball of $\ell_1^2$ and a suitable subset of the sphere. The set $O$ is $\sigma$-convex (and even convex) in some exceptional cases only. Unless the set $A$ contains at most one point on the boundary, the homeomorphism can be modified in such a way that the (modified) $O$ is not $\sigma$-convex.