# Integral means vs infinite convex combinations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, convexity, convex-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal A, \mu)$ be a probability space,  $\mathbb E$  a Banach space, and $f:X\to\mathbb E$  a Bochner integrable function.

> Does there exist a sequence   $(x_k)_{k\ge 1} $ in $X$, and a sequence
> of non-negative numbers $(\lambda_k)_k$ such that
> $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k =1$,
> $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k\|f(x_k)\|<+\infty$ and
> $$\int_Xfd\mu=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k f(x_k)$$ $$?$$

In other words, are all integral means of $f$ already obtained as means over discrete probability measures? We may assume $f$ is bounded, if it helps.

Comment: I think a negative answer should follow from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/357567/35357) and Choquet's theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.
Let $(X, \cal A, \mu)$ be $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.
Let $E = L^2[0,1]$ with inner product $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle := \int \alpha(t)\overline{\beta(t)}\;dt$.
Define $f : [0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ by
$$
f(t) = \mathbf1_{[0,t]}
$$
(I wrote $\mathbf1_S$ for the indicator function of a set $S$.)
Now $f$ is continuous and bounded, so it is Bochner integrable.
The Bochner integral $\psi= \int_0^1 f(t)\;dt$ satisfies:  for all $\alpha \in L^2$,
$$
\langle \psi, \alpha\rangle
=\int_0^1  \psi(s)  \overline{\alpha(s)}\;ds
=\int_0^1 \int_0^1\mathbf1_{[0,t]}(s)\;dt \;\overline{\alpha(s)}\;ds
\\
=\int_0^1 \int_s^1 1\;dt \;\overline{\alpha(s)}\;ds
=\int_0^1 (1-s)\;\overline{\alpha(s)}\;ds
$$
Therefore $\psi(s) = 1-s$ for almost all $s \in [0,1]$.  (Altering $\psi$ on a nullset, we may assume $\psi(s) = 1-s$ for all $s \in [0,1]$.)

Now let us consider
$$
\varphi =\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k f(x_k) ,
$$
where $\lambda_k$ and $x_k$ are as specified.
Can we have $\varphi(s) = 1-s$?
Arguing as before, we conclude
$$
\varphi(s) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k \mathbf1_{[0,x_k]}(s)
= \sum_{x_k \ge s} \lambda_k
$$
for almost all $s$.  (Again we may assume this holds for all $s$.)
Because the $\lambda_k$ are nonnegative, we see that $\varphi$ is a nonincreasing function.  We may assume without loss of generality that the points $x_k$ are all distinct.  Because $\varphi(s) = 1-s$, for some $k$ we have $0 < x_k < 1$ and $\lambda_k > 0$.
By re-labeling, we may assume $0<x_1<1$ and $\lambda_1 > 0$.  Now compute
$$
\lim_{s \nearrow x_1} \varphi(s) = \sum_{x_k \ge x_1}\lambda_k,
\qquad
\lim_{s \searrow x_1} \varphi(s) = \sum_{x_k > x_1}\lambda_k .
$$
The function $\varphi$ has a jump of size $\lambda_1 > 0$ at $x_1$.
Recalling that $\varphi$ is nonincreasing, we conclude that $\varphi(s) = 1-s$ cannot hold almost everywhere.

Thus $\varphi \ne \psi$.

Comment: Fantastic example!

Comment: In order to conclude, can’t we just say that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lambda_k \mathbf1_{[0,x_k]}$, seen as a true  measurable function $[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, has  countable image?  On the contrary,  any representative of $\psi\in L^2([01,])$  must have  image of full measure in $[0,1]$

Comment: Not sure about that "countable image" assertion, in general.  A nice example is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1/2)^k \epsilon_k$ where $\epsilon_k$ are independent random variables with $\epsilon_k = 1$ and $\epsilon_k = 0$ each with probability $1/2$.  Then the sum is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Can we say: for every finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $I:=[0,1]$ the integral $\int_Ifd\mu$ is the distribution function $t\mapsto \mu([t,1])$, so $\mu$ can be recovered from $\int_Ifd\mu$, and different measure give different integrals of $f$.

Comment: In fact if for a  measure $\mu$ on [0,1] we denote $F_\mu$ the distribution function  $t\mapsto \mu([t,1])$, then  the above $f$ is $x\mapsto F_{\delta_x}=\mathbf1_{[0,x]}$,  and  the integral writes $\int_IF_{\delta_x}\mu(x)=F_\mu$.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so. Consider the functions $f(x,y)=e^{ixy},  -1<x<1, y\in \mathbb{R}$. Then,
$$ \int_{-1}^1 f(x,y) \frac{dx}{2} = \frac{\sin(y)}{y}. $$
The question is if this is representable as
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda_k e^{ix_ky} = \frac{\sin(y)}{y} $$ for some $\lambda_k \in (0,1)$ such that $\sum_{k}\lambda_k = 1 $ and $x_k\in (-1,1)$.
Then by taking the generalized Fourier transform you can see that the function on the left has a Fourier transform $\sum_k \lambda_k \delta_k$, while on the write it is $\frac{1}{2}\chi_{(-1,1)}$.
Probably there is a complex analysis way to see this without taking Fourier transform but I do not see it now

Comment: Nice idea.  The series $\sum \lambda_k f(x_k)$ presumably converges in the norm of $E$.  Which (in case $E$ is a space of functions) may or may not imply pointwise convergence.  I spent a lot of space in my solution justifying the pointwise convergence.

Comment: I was probably skipping details, but since the series convergences pointwise the limit must coincide with the norm limit (in any reasonable norm like L2)

Comment: This is also a nice source of examples. Thank you!